# Automatic formatting of list of figures based on separator inside \caption

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I am currently using `caption`/`subcaption` packages to have captions and a list of figures for my thesis.

In my captions, I put a title, but also some legend information as shown by the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% For the sake of example 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Curve}[1]{(\tikz[baseline=-0.6ex,inner sep=0pt] \draw[line width=1pt,#1](0,0) -- (4mm,0);)}

\begin{document}

% Automatic title in list of figures
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{My nice figure with legend. Legend~\Curve{red}}
\end{figure}

% Manual title in list of figures
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption[My nice figure without legend]{My nice figure without legend. Legend~\Curve{red}}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I know it is possible to manually define the caption provided in the list of figures with the optional argument of `\caption[]{}` but is there (it is latex so the question seems dumb) a way to redefine `\caption` so that Everything before a specific character is used as the optional argument.

To be crystal clear:

I would like the ouptut of

```
\caption[blabla]{blabla. blibli}
```

and

```
\caption{blabla. blibli}
```

to look the same in the list of figures.

Comment: What about `\caption{blabla \ignoretherest blibli}`?

Comment: @Werner Well, As I already have a lot of figures in my thesis, I'd prefer not to have to modify everything manually, hence the question... :) . However I think such a solution could still be helpful.

Comment: @Werner To me it looks like the option lists in `pgf-tikz` where each option is separated by a comma. But I have no idea how to reproduce such a behaviour.

Comment: `caption` doesn't like very much that the meaning of `\caption` is changed.

Comment: @egreg I am not very fond of modifying manually the contents of all of my captions and I surely understand your point. I am open to using another macro as searching even in a big document for the `\caption{` string is not that difficult

Comment: @Werner I am now looking for a more general solution for new documents, do you know about a solution that avoids re-defining `\caption` like your `\caption{blabla \ignoretherest blibli}` ?

Comment: @BambOo: Try with [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/6B548if5). Let me know.

Comment: @Werner, unfortunately, this throws *Paragraph ended befor \Courbe was complete* and *Leaders not followed by proper glue* errors ...

Comment: @Werner, egreg's solution actually works with a slight modification: replacing `\l_tmpa_seq { . }` with \l_tmpa_seq { \ignoretherest } and adding `\let\ignoretherest\relax` seems to be working fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of juggling:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

% For the sake of example 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Curve}[1]{%
  (\tikz[baseline=-0.6ex,inner sep=0pt] \draw[line width=1pt,#1](0,0) -- (4mm,0);)%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bamboocaption}{som}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \captioncaption*{#3}
   }
   {
    \IfValueTF{#2}
     {
      \captioncaption[#2]{#3}
     }
     {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { . } { #3 }
      \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq < 2 }
       {% no period
        \captioncaption{#3}
       }
       {
        \captioncaption[\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 }]{#3}
       }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\captioncaption\caption
  \let\caption\bamboocaption
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Body}

% Automatic title in list of figures
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{3cm}
\centering
abc
\caption{Something}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{3cm}
\centering
abc
\caption{Something}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{My nice figure with legend. Legend~\Curve{red}}

\end{figure}

% Manual title in list of figures
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{My nice figure without legend\label{ops}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that the optional argument to `\caption` can still be used with the usual meaning. If not present, the caption will be split at the first period; everything before it is passed as the optional argument for the list of figures. If no period is found, nothing changes from the default.

I also added subcaptions in order to ensure they are not changed. Should you want to add legends also for them it's a bit more complicated.

[image]

Comment: Really nice, as expected everything is possible ;) Thanks.

Comment: There is just a slight remaining glitch. If a `\caption` has no `.` , no explicit option and posesses a `label{}` inside, an error shows up

Comment: @BambOo I added a check for this case.

Comment: Sorry for your trouble, but now I get a weird error `Text line contains an invalid character. l.166 ...865726D6F5C3335316C6173746F64796E616D697`. This is really the first time i see this. Any ideas ? Without adding you patch everything works fine.

Comment: @BambOo That's something different, I guess. My example doesn't raise that error.

Comment: Yes, it is related to the full document I am working on. Upt to know I couldn't figure the location of the bug with precision. I will try to reproduce with a minimal example. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Hey, I just found the issue, probably the last one. If the first `.` of the caption is in math mode then the error shows up. The particular error I got was due to latex trying to compile anyway. For instance you should be able to reproduce using `\caption{My nice figure with legend Legend with some math $a=3.2$~\Curve{red}}`. I like the `\bamboocaption` though ^^

Comment: @BambOo Use `{.}` for periods that you don't want to be mistaken for the delimiter. The idea is not the best, since there are so many possible issues, as you see.

Comment: Just for your information, respecting the limitation with the dot in mathmode, everything works super fine. Thank you very much once again !

Comment: I had another issue with your solution while using the `changes` and `babel` packages. I posted a new question for this matter (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505088/caption-modification-conflicts-with-babel-french-and-changes). If you can explain the issue, you'd be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to use your answer with a macroname as delimiter such as the `\ignoretherest` proposition from Werner ? As you stated using a common character like `.` is a bad choice. If you could add this possibility in your answer, this could benefit a larger audience. I tried some stuff, e.g. replacing `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { . } { #3 }` with `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \ignoretherest } { #3 }` and adding `\let\ignoretherest\relax` but that doesn't do anything of course.

Comment: @BambOo If I change `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {.}` into `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {\ignoretherest}` and define `\ignoretherest` to do nothing, with `\caption{My nice figure with legend \ignoretherest Legend~\Curve{red}}` I get the expected result.

Comment: Ok, I think I did `\def\ignoretherest\relax` instead of `\let\ignoretherest\relax`. I works just fine now thanks !