# Caption modification conflicts with babel french and changes

Tags: captions, babel, changes, babel-french

Following a previous question regarding `caption` modification in a long document (with a [nice solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450286/141947) proposed by @egreg), I ended up using the `changes` package to handle corrections. 
As my document is in french, I also use the `babel` package with `french` option.

Using `[french]{babel}`, `[final]{changes}` and the `caption` redefinition leads to a compilation error

Removing either `{babel}`, `[final]` or the `caption` modification shows no error.

Can anybody clarify the issue ?

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{changes}

% Retouche automatique de la liste des figures
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bamboocaption}{som}
{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
        \captioncaption*{#3}
    }
    {
        \IfValueTF{#2}
        {
            \captioncaption[#2]{#3}
        }
        {
            \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { . } { #3 }
            \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq < 2 }
            {% no period
                \captioncaption{#3}
            }
            {
                \captioncaption[\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 }]{#3}
            }
        }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\captioncaption\caption
    \let\caption\bamboocaption
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{Graph A. Some additional information. \label{figa}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
\caption{Graph B. Some additional information. \label{figb}}
\end{figure}
\added{Discussion about figure~\ref{figa}}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Log file error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\r@figa ->{1}{1}{\seq 
                      _item:Nn \l _tmpa_seq {1}}{figure.caption.1}{}
l.57 \added{Discussion about figure~\ref{figa}}
```

**EDIT** File list

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
  lipsum.sty    2019/01/02 v2.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
   expl3.sty    2019-08-14 L3 programming layer (loader)
expl3-code.tex    2019-08-14 L3 programming layer
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental backend support: PDF mode

  xparse.sty    2019-05-28 L3 Experimental document command parser
  lipsum.ltd
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
dvipsnam.def    2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
  svgnam.def    2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   babel.sty    2019/07/19 3.33 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
  french.ldf    2019/03/30 v3.5e French support from the babel system
scalefnt.sty
 caption.sty    2018/10/06 v3.3-154 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2018/09/12 v1.8c caption3 kernel (AR)
hyperref.sty    2019/06/12 v6.88h Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2019/06/12 v6.88h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2019/06/12 v6.88h Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 changes.sty    2019/07/21 v3.1.3 changes package
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 xifthen.sty    2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 ifmtarg.sty    2018/04/16 v1.2b check for an empty argument
 xstring.sty    2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
pdfcolmk.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Color support for pdfTeX via marks (HO)
    ulem.sty    2012/05/18
todonotes.sty    2018/11/22
    tikz.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
     pgf.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  pgfsys.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  pgffor.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
 pgfkeys.sty
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
truncate.sty    2001/08/20  ver 3.6
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
    test.out
    test.out
example-image-a.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
example-image-b.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
```

Comment: On my system, when I add `\usepackage{graphicx}` at the start, the code runs without error (and produces the desired effect with the additional information stripped from the List of Figures). Which error message do you get exactly?

Comment: @Marijn I added the errror in my question. It seems that the `\caption` modification is treated as a string and not evaluated... Or maybe I am totally mistaken.
If I ignore the error, the document seems ok, but I'd prefer not leave it this way.
I also added the `graphicx` package and the same error shows up

Comment: It is a string (see the `.aux` file at the `\newlabel` statements) but that should not be a problem. Maybe and old version of something, could you post the `*File List*` that you get by putting `\listfiles` below `\documentclass{article}`? This list is visible in the terminal and in the log file, near the end.

Comment: @Marijn I added the file list, all my packages are up-to-date according to miktex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the expansion of `\seq_item:Nn`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[final]{changes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Retouche automatique de la liste des figures

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bamboocaption}{som}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \captioncaption*{#3}
   }
   {
    \IfValueTF{#2}
     {
      \captioncaption[#2]{#3}
     }
     {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { . } { #3 }
      \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq < 2 }
       {% no period
        \captioncaption{#3}
       }
       {
        \use:x{\exp_not:N \captioncaption[\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 }]\exp_not:n{{#3}}}
       }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\captioncaption\caption
  \let\caption\bamboocaption
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{Graph A. Some additional information. \label{figa}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
\caption{Graph B. Some additional information. \label{figb}}
\end{figure}
\added{Discussion about figure~\ref{figa}}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure, can you explain when the caption modification is made ? I had the impression that with the previous solution, the modification was treated as a string in the first pass, then evaluated during the second run. I don't think I understand the process.

Comment: Your solution works on the MWE, however, when I apply it to my original document, I still have (different errors). In the `.lof` file, for captions containing `\added` `\replaced` or `\deleted` calls, I may get `\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {IV.9}{\ignorespaces \added [id=N}}{107}{figure.caption.135}`... I think I will remove all of these calls from the captions.